# Meaning of ARM operand [r0]!

Tags: arm, neon

I have just encountered the instruction:

```
vld1.16 {d0}, [r1]!
```

I am confused as to what the ! means when appended to the pointer [r1]. How is this different to the instruction:

```
vld1.16 {d0}, [r1]
```

Thanks for taking a look at this question.

Comment: Step 1: look at pretty much any [documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1359731153545.html) on ARM assembly [addressing modes](http://www.heyrick.co.uk/assembler/str.html). Step 2: ??? Step 3: Profit!

Comment: Hi. I got the part about pre-indexed addressing modes. Does that mean [r1]! accesses the 16x4 vector from the pointer, and then increments to the next vector, where [r1] simply accesses and does not increment? I apologize for these basic questions. I have not programmed in assembly previously in more than an academic setting.

Comment: Yes. Admittedly the NEON structure load/stores differ slightly from the norm in that the writeback offset is implicit in the size of the target structure, but that's nothing [the instruction description itself](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1361289956432.html) doesn't cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!` causes `r1` to be updated after the memory access to the next address after the loaded memory.

For example, `VLD1.16 {d0}, [r1]!` does the same thing as:

```
VLD1.16 {d0}, [r1]
ADD r1, r1, #8
```